# How to use Form Fields in Subject Line of email?

Tags: forms, email, pdf, livecycle-designer

I have a PDF form (in Adobe Livecycledesigner8.2) that is used to certify the restoration of pavement. Within that form I have a button to email me the form. It is the Adobe button object with a Submit Control Type.

I get the email but I want to include in the Subject line of the email a few of the forms values, which I cannot do.

I have this:

```
mailto:paving@MYDOMAIN.com?subject="Certificate " + TextField1.Value + ".pdf"
```

The subject comes through exactly as it is typed above and does not retrieve the field value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `TextField1.rawValue` or `.formattedValue` instead of `.Value`

When I want to submit the PDF via E-Mail I usually just add a regular button and add this code in the "click"-Event: (I set the 4 variables "to,cc,emailSubject" and "Msg" before)

```
var emailSubject = "Certificate " + TextField1.rawValue + ".pdf";
event.target.mailDoc({
                    bUI:        false,
                    cTo:        to,
                    cCC:        cc,
                    cSubject:   emailSubject,
                    cMsg:       emailMsg,
                    cSubmitAs:  "PDF"   
            });
```